# Make a 2 dimensional array with javascript or D3.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, d3.js

I have 3 separate array's that i want to convert to one 2-dimensional array so i can use it for D3.js

Example of the arrays that i have:

```
var data1 = [ 0.10, 0.09, 0.08, 0.07, 0.06, ... ]; // series 1
var data2 = [ 0.10, 0.09, 0.08, 0.07, 0.06, ... ]; // series 2
var data3 = [ 0.10, 0.09, 0.08, 0.07, 0.06, ... ]; // series 3
```

What i want:

```
var data = [
              [ 0.10, 0.09, 0.08, 0.07, 0.06, ... ], // series 1
              [ 0.10, 0.09, 0.08, 0.07, 0.06, ... ], // series 2
              [ 0.10, 0.09, 0.08, 0.07, 0.06, ... ]  // series 3
            ];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Anything wrong with just doing this?

```
data = [data1, data2, data3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

`var data = [data1, data2, data3]`

However this means if you mutate `data1`, `data2`, or `data3`, you'll also mutate `data`.

You can use something like:

`var data = [data1.slice(0), data2.slice(0), data3.slice(0)]`

if you want to modify `data1`, `data2`, or `data3` afterwards without changing `data`.