# d3.js Two Dimensional Array Bar Chart

Tags: javascript, arrays, svg, d3.js, charts

I am trying to make a bar chart containing 3 'groups' of data in d3.js. I have been able to implement the example from "Let's Make a Bar Chart" sample http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/2/, but am wondering how you would implement that with a 2 dimensional data set instead.

I'm having a bit of a tough time wrapping my head around what I feel should be a fairly straight forward process (select first index of 2d array -> iterate through that array and display the values of each element in bars -> select second index of array -> iterate through that array and display the value of each element in bars etc...), so examples would be hugely appreciated.

The code thus far is:

```
var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];*/

var width = Math.max(500, innerWidth), height = Math.max(500, innerHeight), barHeight = 80;

var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(data)]).range([0, width]);

var chart = d3.select(".chart").attr("width", width).attr("height", barHeight * data.length * 3);

var bar = chart.selectAll("g").data(data).enter().append("g").attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * barHeight + ")"; });

bar.append("rect").attr("width", x).attr("height", barHeight - 1);

bar.append("text").attr("x", function(d) { return x(d) - 3; }).attr("y", barHeight / 2).attr("dy", ".35em").text(function(d) { return d; });
```

however I would like to change the "data" variable to be:

```
var data = [[40,45,5],
            [50,49,2],
            [60,62,4],
            [40,41,6],
            [42,40,3],
            [65,67,10],
            [70,67,17],
            [66,65,2],
            [45,44,3],
            [39,38,7],
            [38,38,8],
            [45,40,4],
            [43,35,3],
            [50,65,8],
            [51,50,6]];
```

Comment: It sounds like you want [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make a 2 dimensional array with javascript or D3.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13591676/make-a-2-dimensional-array-with-javascript-or-d3-js)